# Meaning of て form + えん

Tags: conjugations, て-form

I was watching an episode of One Piece, and while studying the transcript, I came across this sentence.

```
ルフィに　会いてえんなら俺が　教えてやるよ
```

Ace told the other pirates "If ya wanna meet Luffy, I'll tell ya where he is". In the word 会いてえん, what does the えん　part mean? Is it some sort of grammar construct? Is it commonly used in colloquial Japanese? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ～え is the casual form of elongating イ-adjectives into ～え.  So in this case it is really `会いたい` getting changed into `会いてえ`.  There may be another topic here about this form, but I can't find it.

The ～ん is just the abbreviated ～の nominalizer.  The same as ～んです.

Comment: Is there a reason I got two downvotes on this answer?

Comment: Is this の(ん) really a nominalizer? I'm not sure about the grammatical role of this "の", but I feel this の or ん before なら is simply optional (会いてえのなら／会いてえんなら／会いてえなら all sounds OK).

Comment: 「会いたいのなら」は、「会いたいなら」にはない、「会いたいということなら」というニュアンスが含まれると思うので、その「の」は nominalizer だと思います。

Comment: This is a regional phenomenon.  I would have expected the region named in a good answer.

Comment: This is def a nominalizer. If you can't let us know what region it's specific to, don't downvote.

Comment: (Don't worry, I'm the upvoter) 「違えねえ」「痛え」「遅え」みたいなのは、いわゆる「[東京方言](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9D%B1%E4%BA%AC%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80)」ないし「江戸訛り」の類でしたっけ。nominalizerの件はすみません、深く考えず聞いただけなので気にしないで下さい。

Comment: I think whether it is a nominalizer or not is not an interesting question anyways. A "nominalizer" is a purely syntactic concept, and I don't think it matters too much whether you analyze 会いたいの as a noun or not in this case. The more interesting question is what it's doing semantically (and its syntactic status will probably follow).